# What is "If you're tired" called in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

"If you're tired, you should sleep."

What is the name for the phrase "If you're tired" in this sentence?  Obviously "you should sleep" could stand alone as a sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to call it an ***if*-clause**, or the ***conditional part***.

I suppose you *may* call it the [***πρότασις***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protasis_(linguistics)) if you’d really like to, but that’s a bit rich for my blood — even when transliterated into Latin letters as ***protasis***.

Note that the ordering does not matter; the conditional part is set in bold in all these examples, no matter whether it comes first or second, and no matter its spelling:

- **If you’re tired,** sleep.
- **If you’re tired,** you should sleep.
- Sleep **if you’re tired.**
- I’d sleep **if I were that tired.**
- **Unless I were incredibly tired,** I wouldn’t sleep in my car.
- I wouldn’t sleep here **unless I were dead-tired.**
- **Should you become too weary to drive safely,** pull over immediately and take a nap!
- **If Santa Clause was already here,** then how come the chimney’s still plugged with that old crow’s nest?

For the protatically inclined, the other part of the conditional (that is, its consequent) is called the [***ἁπόδοσις***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodosis), or if you prefer, the ***apodosis***.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **subordinate clause**.  Refer to http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/subclterm.htm and http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subordinate%2Bclause .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling the protasis the "condition," and calling the apodosis the "consequence."